# Episerver access right on block level for local blocks

Tags: c#, episerver

I have global blocks that allow me to adjust access right though the "visible to: everyone" and then a link to "manage" on top. But for blocks I create directly on the page, I get the "visible to: Everyone" and no link to manage. Also these blocks are not visible in the admin panel access rights.

So I have a question: Why would it be different for local blocks? Maybe there is an argument to not implement it at all?

P.S. I found a way to solve it with a direct iframe link to the access rights of a block, I just want to make sure it'll not mess anything

Answer (score 1):

Assets (blocks and files) stored in the page/content asset folder inherits access rights from its owner content. You can copy and paste the blocks to another (global) folder, then you can manage the access rights independently.